# What to do with copy-pasted answers by a new user?

Tags: discussion, answers, new-users

Just now I've opened the main page of the site, and see that a new user has copy-pasted effectively the same text to 3 posts (last two of which are apparently duplicates of each other, since the answers on them are effectively the same).  How to handle such situation ?

Answer itself potentially could be working, but the fact that user has copy pasted it in short period of time, suggests to me they didn't put much thought into solution.

The mentioned posts:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/925896/295286
- https://askubuntu.com/a/925897/295286
- https://askubuntu.com/a/925895/295286

Answer (score 14):

This happens quite often. If I'm not wrong, the system automatically flags identical posts, so it's likely to be looked into by mods.

In my opinion, there's no automatic conclusion to be drawn.

Often, if the same answer works for multiple questions they should really be closed as duplicates, and the new user, who I assume is acting in good faith, should be advised about our preference for not duplicating content. The questions may be duped or merged and duplicate answers possibly deleted.

On the other hand, sometimes the same answer works for two or three slightly different questions, in which case there's nothing wrong.

On the... third hand, the user may be inexperienced with Ubuntu as well as with SE, and may be posting some random generic solution everywhere it looks like it might possibly fit. This calls for detailed comments and probably downvotes, maybe even flags if they seemingly aren't reading the question or are duplicating existing answers on the page.